# Passing the view in onClick to a private class causes the wrong object to be sent

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

What im trying to do is display a checkbox, a button and a spinner in a TableLayout. The values are obtained from a web service and tableRows are added dynamically to the TableLayout.

The first button creates a dialog with a listview. The listview contains the numbers 1-30. When the user clicks selects a value in the ListView, i need the text of the button to change to the value clicked. 
The code works for the first button that is clicked(The first time the listview is opened and a value is selected the text of the button is changed). But the second time i open the list view and select a button, the text of the first button changes and not the one which was clicked. What am i doing wrong?

```
protected void fillTableView() {
    for (MedicineInfo temp : orderedMedList) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.neworderrestockmedicinelist2, tlOrderInfo, false);
        CheckBox cbMedicine = (CheckBox) tr
                .findViewById(R.id.cbNewOrderRestockMedName);
        cbMedicine.setText(temp.vcProduct);
        Button btnQty = (Button) tr
                .findViewById(R.id.btnNewOrderRestockQty);
        Spinner spnIntakeUnit = (Spinner) tr
                .findViewById(R.id.spnNewOrderRestockIntakeUnit);
        IntakeUnitAdapter intakeUnitAda = new IntakeUnitAdapter(this);
        spnIntakeUnit.setAdapter(intakeUnitAda);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAda = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numberArray);
        arrayAda.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        tlOrderInfo.addView(tr);
        btnQty.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dlgQty = new Dialog(mContext);
                TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();
                ListView lvQty = new ListView(mContext);
                QuantityAdapter qtyAda = new QuantityAdapter(mContext);
                lvQty.setAdapter(qtyAda);
                dlgQty.addContentView(lvQty,
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ItemSelectTest test = new ItemSelectTest(tr);
                lvQty.setOnItemClickListener(test);
                showDialog(DLG_QTY);
                test = null;

            }
        });
    }
}

private class ItemSelectTest implements OnItemClickListener {
    Button btn = null;

    public ItemSelectTest(TableRow tr) {
        Button bt = (Button) tr.findViewById(R.id.btnNewOrderRestockQty);
        btn = bt;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(arg3));
    }

}
```

In the same shown above, i'm passing the TableRow that contains the button. I've also tried passing v from onClick. The problem is the same either way..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the way that you're showing the dialog. If you look at the docs for `showDialog` ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)):

> Show a dialog managed by this activity. A call to onCreateDialog(int,
>   Bundle) will be made with the same id the first time this is called
>   for a given id. From thereafter, the dialog will be automatically
>   saved and restored.

Presumably you're returning `dlgQty` in `onCreateDialog`. The thing is, that dialog will be cached after the first time. A quick fix for this is to always call `removeDialog` when you are [done with it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#removeDialog%28int%29).

Comment: Thank you very much... I added removeDialog to onItemClick and it worked like clockwork